# How to push a Git update for my Rails app on DotCloud.com without loosing the SQLite prod db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, sqlite, dotcloud

This could be a noob problem but I couldn't find a solution so far.
I'm developing a Rails app locally that uses SQLite, I've set up a local Git repo, and the dotcloud push command is using this. Locally I use the dev environment and on DotCloud it automatically uses  the prod env, which is great. The problem is that each time I do a push my prod db on DotCloud gets lost, no matter how minor the changes are to the codebase, and I have to run 'rake db:migrate' to set it up again. I don't have a prod db locally, only the dev and test dbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that every time you deploy, the old version of your deployed app is wiped, and replaced with the new code, and your sqlite db is usually within your app files. I'm not a dotcloud user I don't know it it works, but you can try to setup a shared folder, where you put the production database on the server, which is outside of your rails app.

Answer (score 3):

Put your DB in ~/data/ as described [here](http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.4/guides/persistent-data/)  and create a symbolic link at deploy time:

```
ln -s ~/data/production.sqlite3 ~/current/db/production.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 2):

You should *not* have your SQLite database file in version control.  If you had multiple developers it would conflict every single time somebody merges the latest changes.  And as you've noticed, it will also be pushed up to production.

You should add the db file to [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).  If it's already in version control, you'll probably have to `git rm` the file first.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure how git is setup on DotCloud.com, but I'm assuming there is a bare repo that you push to and another repo that pull from the bare when a suitable git hook has been executed. You need to find out if you can configure that last pull to use the **ours** merge strategy.